# jQuery prettyPhoto not working with Flip! Plugin

Tags: jquery, html, flip, prettyphoto

I've just read this post: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760694/jquery-prettyphoto-not-working-with-sponsor-flip-wall-plugin), but it doesn't do any help in fact...

I'm having a problem like the link above, but i'm using HTML instead of PHP.
And also, using the [Flip! Plugin](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/).

The first time i open my page, the prettyPhoto works, but when i make a flip, it doesn't work anymore.

There are the code for calling the PrettyPhoto:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#box").prettyPhoto();
});
```

And there is my first link:

```
<div id="flipTwoQuali">
 <a id="box" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l34c7wBEdmI" rel="prettyPhoto" title="">
 <img src="img/nossasacoes/qualificacao/video.png" />
 </a>
</div>
```

And here is when i click the menu, the #flipTwoQuali div changes its contents to this (this is inside *flipQuali.js*, on the *flipNE()* function:

```
<div id="flipTwoQuali">
 <a id="box" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8PFPXox9Rk" rel="prettyPhoto" title="">
 <img src="img/nossasacoes/qualificacao/ne/img02.png" />
 </a>
</div>
```

Just the video and the image changes, but the prettyPhoto don`t work anymore.... =/

I've it online, [HERE](http://efdutra.com/abril/fvc). Click on INICIAR (the green arrow) and on the video (The image with the Play Button). Then try to flip, clicking on NOVA ESCOLA (on the gray menu), and clicking on the image on the same position that you clicked the video before, it won't work anymore!!

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Just tested it out in Chrome and Firefox and everything seems to work fine.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox. But the prettyphoto works before you do the flip, When you flip the page, it dont work anymore, the video opens on the page, instead inside the prettyphoto. Cant be working!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`ve already fix it!

Thats too Simple!

the Flip! Plugin, has a callback called onend

then, i add to my script:

```
onEnd: function(){
        $('[rel*="prettyPhoto"]').prettyPhoto();
    }
```

It works!!